# Error en conexión localhost php 5.6

Tags: php, php5

hola buenas a todos pues vengo a pedirles una ayuda la verdad me esta partiendo la cabeza esto hace unos días me entregaron en el trabajo y esta echo en php 5.6, hasta ahí todo bien el problema es cuando intento levantar el sistema en local como ocupo laragon se me hizo sencillo instalar php en esa versión del sistema 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora el sistema me levanta correctamente como ven acá.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando intento logearme con el admin y admin por defecto me sale el dichoso error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que he visto es que tiene 5 archivos de conexion y aca les dejo el código de cada uno de ellos
bueno serian 6 archivos hay un archivo con el nombre de db.php que son los parámetros

archivo db.php

```
<?php
    /*-------------------------
    Conexion para las custodias
    ---------------------------*/
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");//DB_HOST:  generalmente suele ser "127.0.0.1"
define("DB_NAME", "activos");//Nombre de la base de datos
define("DB_USER", "root");//Usuario de tu base de datos
define("DB_PASS", "");//Contraseña del usuario de la base de datos
```

archivo config.php

```
<?php
/*-------------------------
    Conexion para configuracion principal del proyecto
    ---------------------------*/
session_start();
//session_regenerate_id();
date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');

class Conectar
{

    public function con()
    {
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
        //mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        mysql_select_db("activos");
        return $con;
    }

    public static function ruta()
    {
        return "http://siacfi.test/";
    }

    public function comillas_inteligentes($valor)
    {
        // Retirar las barras
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $valor = stripslashes($valor);
        }

        // Colocar comillas si no es entero
        if (!is_numeric($valor)) {
            $valor = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($valor) . "'";
        }
        return $valor;
    }
    //funci�n para la fecha
public static function fecha(){
    $dia=date("w");
    $day=date("d");
    $mes=date("m");
switch ($dia) {
    case 0:
    $dia ="Domingo";
    break;

  case 1:
  $dia = "Lunes";
    break;
    case 2:
  $dia ="Martes";

          break;

  case 3:
  $dia ="Mi�rcoles";

          break;
  case 4:
    $dia ="Jueves";
    break;
  case 5:
  $dia ="Viernes";
    break;
  case 6:
  $dia ="S�bado";
    break;

}
switch ($mes){
    case '01':
    $mes="Enero";
    break;
    case '02':
    $mes="Febrero";
    break;
    case '03':
    $mes="Marzo";
    break;
    case '04':
    $mes="Abril";
    break;
    case '05':
    $mes="Mayo";
    break;
    case '06':
    $mes="Junio";
    break;
    case '07':
    $mes="Julio";
    break;
    case '08':
    $mes="Agosto";
    break;
    case '09':
    $mes="Septiembre";
    break;
    case '10':
    $mes="Octubre";
    break;
    case '11':
    $mes="Noviembre";
    break;
    case '12':
    $mes="Diciembre";
    break;
}
$fecha="$dia ".$day." de ".$mes." de ".date("Y");
return $fecha; 
}

}

?>
```

archivo de conexion.php

```
<?php
    /*-------------------------
    Conexion para las custodias
    ---------------------------*/
    # conectare la base de datos
    $con=@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if(!$con){
        die("imposible conectarse: ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Conexión falló: ".phpinfo().mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

archivo de conexion1.php

```
<?php
/*-------------------------
    Conexion para combos de 2 y 3 niveles
    ---------------------------*/
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db("activos");


//*************************************************************

//Convierto los acentos a HTML

function chao_tilde($entra)

{

$traduce=array( '�' => '&aacute;' , '�' => '&eacute;' , '�' => '&iacute;' , '�' => '&oacute;' , '�' => '&uacute;' , '�' => '&ntilde;' , '�' => '&Ntilde;' , '�' => '&auml;' , '�' => '&euml;' , '�' => '&iuml;' , '�' => '&ouml;' , '�' => '&uuml;');

$sale=strtr( $entra , $traduce );

return $sale;

}
?>
```

archivo de conexion2.php

```
<?php
/*-------------------------
    Conexion para reportes ireports
    ---------------------------*/

$Conexion= new  JdbcConnection("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","jdbc:mysql://localhost/siacfi","root","");
$ubicacion= 'C://xampp//htdocs//siacfi//reportes_javabridge//reportes//';
$destino= 'C://xampp//htdocs//siacfi//reportes_javabridge//';

//*************************************************************

?>
```

archivo de cconexion3.php

```
<?php
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";//poner tu propia contraseña, si tienes una.
    $bd = "activos";
       // $usuariologueo=$_SESSION["ses_codusuario"];

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $bd);
         mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    if (!$conexion){ 

        die('Error de Conexión: ' .mysqli_connect_errno());    
    }   
?>
```

como ven he estado intentado usar el mysqli por desde la versión php5.6 ya esta disponible bueno al menos eso pude notar pero he estado intentando muchas formas y siempre llego a la misma de usar mysqli bueno espero puedan ayudarme para poder levantarlo en local espero una ayuda gracias de antemano

Comment: tu error es que estas utilizando mysql y no estas pasando la conexion debe ser   mysqli en la linea 16 esta:  `mysql_select_db("activos");` cuando deberia ser `mysqli_select_db($con,"activos");` o pasado directamente `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "activos");`

Comment: Estás mezclando funciones de dos APIs distintas: una es **`mysql_`** que es obsoleta y no funciona en PHP 7+  y la otra es **`mysqli_`**  que es una versión mejorada de la anterior. Dado que hay una mínima diferencia de una `i` es fácil confundirse. Hay más cosas que cambian y mejoran en `mysqli_`, deberías leer la documentación para conocerla. En el código, debes cambiar todas las `mysql_` por `mysqli_`  adaptando los parámetros que lo requieran porque las dos APIs no son 100% iguales en la sintaxis.

Comment: estoy usando php5.6 pero cuando corrijo errores me sale mas errores aumente la zona horaria mi linea 13 que es esta mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); al colocarlo asi me salen estos errores  Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in line 13
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in  line 32
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in  line 32
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in  line 62 ahora lo que he me dirian ustedes es que tengo que cambiar todo a mysqli